# Dividing a number $a$ into summands $x, y, z$ to maximize $x y^2 z^3$

Tags: calculus, optimization

This problem is simple if we use the Lagrange multiplier method, taking $f = xy^{2}z^{3}$ and the constraint $x+y+z=a$, where $a$ is number to be divided. I have solved problem this way? Are there any other ways to solve this problem?

Comment: I think that Lagrange multiplier method is really the simplest one since, if we exclude the trivial solution $\lambda=0$, only one solution is left.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One can solve for one of the variables in the constraint, say, $$x = a - y - z,$$ and then substitute to give the value of quantity $f$ to be maximized in terms of the remaining variables:
$$f = (a - y - z) y^2 z^3.$$
Now, $y, z$ are unconstrained so this becomes a standard exercise in maximizing a multivariable function: Solve the system
$$f_y = 0, \qquad f_z = 0,$$
and then analyze the behavior of $f$ at each critical point.

Comment: That would certainly make sense (so that one doesn't, e.g., choose $y$ to be a negative number arbitrarily far from zero), but of course the OP doesn't say as much. Including such a constraint is also routine, and in this case it's particularly easy: When $y$, $z$, or $y + z$ is $0$ or $a$, $f = 0$, which is not a global maximum (provided $a > 0$ anyway) because when $x = y = z = \frac{a}{3}$, $f > 0$. So, it's enough to proceed as above and simply discard any critical points that doesn't satisfy the given constraints.

Comment: You're welcome, Sophie, I hope it helped. And yes, the method of Lagrange multipliers is especially nice in this case, and I'd recommend it first provided you're comfortable with it.